# HTML multiple select box

Tags: html, forms

I am just wondering what's the name of the below form? I was Googling from morning for the list of HTML forms but I couldn't find this kind of form anywhere. Can anyone tell me the exact name of this form and is this available in HTML forms?

[image]

I just want to add this kind of form in my website. Is that available for HTML or should I use JavaScript or its only limited for Windows applications?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Here's a little sample to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/eUDRV/3/

This example will move items (one or multiple) from the left to the right and back again. Whatever item(s) are selected in the right side will update the textbox on the right side.

We are using the elements:

- `select`
- `input type="button"`
- `input type="text"`

Framed by:

- `div`
- `section`

Styled with simple CSS. Functionality is provided with JavaScript.

I'm using the jQuery library to make things a little easier. This could also be done with pure JavaScript.

```js
$("#btnLeft").click(function () {
    var selectedItem = $("#rightValues option:selected");
    $("#leftValues").append(selectedItem);
});

$("#btnRight").click(function () {
    var selectedItem = $("#leftValues option:selected");
    $("#rightValues").append(selectedItem);
});

$("#rightValues").change(function () {
    var selectedItem = $("#rightValues option:selected");
    $("#txtRight").val(selectedItem.text());
});
```

```css
SELECT, INPUT[type="text"] {
    width: 160px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
SECTION {
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    overflow: auto;
}
SECTION > DIV {
    float: left;
    padding: 4px;
}
SECTION > DIV + DIV {
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
    <div>
        <select id="leftValues" size="5" multiple></select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnLeft" value="&lt;&lt;" />
        <input type="button" id="btnRight" value="&gt;&gt;" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <select id="rightValues" size="4" multiple>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
        </select>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtRight" />
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: <select id="rightValues" size="4" multiple>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
        </select>
Can you please tell me what is how to restrict a user to select only a limited number of items available? Say i just want that user can select only 2 of the 3 options?

Comment: What's the text box (txtRight) for?

Comment: @MarbellaConsulting - the textbox is to match the screenshot in the original question and to show how changing the selected values can update another element.

Comment: @Beofett - it works for me in IE8 document mode (IE11) and on a true IE8 VM. However, JS Fiddle is broken in IE8, so you would need to view the example at: http://fiddle.jshell.net/eUDRV/3/show/. Also, I used an `section` tag in the example so IE8 would require an HTML 5 shim to make it work (or use another tag). Let me know if you found another problem.

Comment: @TimMedora Please accept my apologies.  This was absolutely a PEBKAC problem on my end.  This does work just fine in IE8.