# How to set "all values" as default in a multiple select?

Tags: html, select

There are questions on how to make one selection default, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3518002/1801588). But I have a multiple select and want all the options to be selected initially. I found questions for something similar (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15696415/1801588)), but not exactly what I want.

Is this possible without JavaScript?

Comment: Often, on webpages or native apps alike, the behavior of no selection is the same as all selected. If you do that, you can default to blank selection. Don't know if that makes sense for what you're doing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/UgHT5/  is this your need?

```
<select multiple>
    <option selected>a</option>
    <option selected>b</option>
    <option selected>c</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It is. See my answer - it's basically the same.

Answer (score 5):

It's much easier than I expected:

```
<select multiple name="type">
    <option selected value="1">type 1</option>
    <option selected value="2">type 2</option>
    <option selected value="3">type 3</option>
</select>
```

To find [this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp) was enough.