# Rails multiple select box many to many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have added a multiple select box like this one to my form [HTML multiple select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696415/html-multiple-select-box).

I have a User object and a Personality object. A user can have 0 or more personalities and a personality can "belong" to 0 or more users. For this many to many relation I created a third model UserPersonality to store the ids of the User and Personality.

My User and Personality models have their corresponding `has_many through` indications. My question is, how can I make the helper add the association to the UserPersonality table through a select box like the one on the left from the link provided?
If a user adds a personality from the right select box to the left box I want to add a record such as:

```
UserId  PersonalityId
1         3
```

To connect a User with the Personality that is selected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was easier to solve the problem using the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association vs the `has_many through`

This is because I'm only using the join table for the ids and with this association I can simply do

```
u=User.find(1)
p=Personality.find(1)
u.personalities << p
```

To associate them and populate the joint table: `users_personalities`