# Multi select listing

Tags: jquery, html

How would you go about creating a multi list selection area.
You should be able to double click on a item on the left to add it to a selected area
and you should be able to double click on the selected area to remove a item from the list(selected).

> ```
> <ul id="selection">
>     <li><span>Apple</span></li>
>     <li><span>Pear</span></li>
>     <li><span>Banana</span></li>
>     <li><span>Melon</span></li>
> </ul>
>
>
>
> <ul id="selected">
>     <li><span>Mango</span></li>
> </ul>
> ```

Ive tried to play around with adding ad removing clases in JQuery, but it just did not work.

Please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696415/html-multiple-select-box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helping a nother Morne, sure thing

Ive got just the thing you need
Hope it will help

http://jsfiddle.net/nel_mo/Y5256/

> ```
> // Copy over on double click and  // Delete on double click on
> selected side
>     $('#selection').on('dblclick', 'li', function() {
>         $('#selected').append($(this).clone());
>     });
>
>
>     $('#selected').on('dblclick', 'li', function() {
>         $(this).remove();
>     });
>
>
>
> // Move over and back on double click on each side
>     $('#selection').on('dblclick', 'li', function() {
>         $('#selected').append($(this).clone());
>         $(this).remove();
>     });
>
>
>     $('#selected').on('dblclick', 'li', function() {
>         $('#selection').append($(this).clone());
>         $(this).remove();
>     });
> ```

Good luck