# Advanced multiple select box for symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

I am using symfony2

I have Manytomany entity and using multiple select box like this.

in php

```
    ->add('availLangs','entity',array(
            'class' => 'UserBundle:Lang',
            'label' => 'form.availLangs',
            'multiple' => true))
```

in twig

```
{{ form_widget(form.availLangs) }}
```

[image]

It's nicely simple though,however when there are many choices(like 10~), the situation could be chaos for user.

So I am trying to implement choose box like this

[HTML multiple select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696415/html-multiple-select-box)

or

Some widget to select multiple items from many items easily.

Is there good reference for implement with symfony2 or formbuilder?

Comment: One good bundle (there are more) is GenemuFormBundle. I like it. I think the select2 component may be usefull for you.

Comment: thank you Yenne Info. For now I will use select2 though, I will check your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `select2` jquery widget , it has a nice search input where you can type some characters of the desired option and the widget will get them to you.
https://select2.github.io/

**Sample :** http://jsfiddle.net/eoaa2wqw/

In symfony2 , just add `select2` class to your input through builder or twig

```
->add('availLangs','entity',array(
            'class' => 'UserBundle:Lang',
            'label' => 'form.availLangs',
            'attr'=> array('class'=> 'select2') <-- here 
            'multiple' => true))
```

then acitivate select2 with :

```
$('.select2').select2(// options maybe ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks This widget is really great and good for me. thanks very much